# PHP move_uploaded_file uploads only one file

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I'm testing uploads on 3 files on my desktop `test.xlsx`, `test - Copy.xlsx`, and `test - Copy (2).xlsx`. My PHP script is breaking at the line where my `move_uploaded_files` statement is. I get the error `move_uploaded_file(uploads/test - Copy.xlsx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. **BUT** `test - Copy (2).xlsx` is uploaded when I check my uploads folder. My PHP is as follows:

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key=>$value){
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES['file']['error'][$key];
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$key];
    if(){
        //validation
    } else{ //if validated
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, 'uploads/'.$fileName)){
          //do more stuff
        } else{
            echo "Upload failed.";
        }
    }
}
```

The //do more stuff actually runs once for `test - Copy (2).xlsx` (the only file uploaded successfully). My JS script is below but I doubt that's the part that's breaking since when I print_r($_FILES) in PHP, all files appear in the output.

```
var upload = function(event){
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files;
    var data = new FormData();
    for (i=0; i<file.length; i++){
        data.append('file[]', file[i]);
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', completeHandler, false);
    request.addEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);
    request.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler, false);
    request.open('POST', 'php/excel_upload_read.php');
    request.send(data);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks fine, are you sure the things in the `if` statement or in the `//do more stuff` are not messing things up? And have you tried a non-ajax, regular form submit to test the php?

Comment: Hi jeroen, you bring up a good point. I'm reading in the excel files with PHPExcel. When I comment out the script, all 3 files upload! I guess my problem now is my PHPExcel script :/

Comment: Well, at least you know where to look :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the multi-dimensional array in the wrong order. Try this:

```
foreach($_FILES['file'] as $key=>$value){
    $fileName = $_FILES['file'][$key]['name'];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES['file'][$key]['tmp_name'];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES['file'][$key]['error'];
    $type = $_FILES['file'][$key]['type'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way `$_FILES` global is structured, it does not let you iterate easily.

You can use this function it s meant to reorganize the data structure

```
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}
```

Then you can use foreach easily:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_POST)) {
    $files = reArrayFiles($_FILES['file']);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $temp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $path = 'uploads/'.$file['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $path)){
            echo 'Upload succesful';
        }else{
            echo 'failed to upload';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'file not uploaded';
}
```

This function `reArrayFiles` was posted by someone in the PHP documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: thanks for the tip meda! I'll try it out but I commented above in my question. When I comment out the `//do something` part, the uploads work fine. The `do something` part is reading in the excel files I'm uploading. I'll try out your method and let you know!

Comment: Oh okay so the issue is not the uploading part then